# If I have 10 branches locally, how to push them to remote origin server?

Tags: git

If I have 10 branches locally, how to push them to remote origin server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`git push origin --all`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) will push all refs under `refs/heads/`

Comment: Looks like it does.  Much better than my answer.

Comment: Or setup push refspec in config file for given remote.